# Should I change question title of: Some services won't start a startup?

Tags: discussion, question-titles

I answered this question: [Some services won't start a startup?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/527402/some-services-wont-start-a-startup) and, as OP said, it seems that workaround fix the problem.

Later I found this question: [Sickbeard start service on boot not working: Permissions issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/529767/sickbeard-start-service-on-boot-not-working-permissions-issue?noredirect=1#comment729632_529767) and agree with the OP, I improved my [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/527402/some-services-wont-start-a-startup/528346#528346) and flag her question as duplicate.

But now I wonder whether it is better to change the title from:

```
   Some services won't start a startup?
```

to something like:

```
  Sickbeard and Sabnzbdplus won't start at boot
```

Should I change question title? If yes, could you help me to choose better title?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Something like "Sickbeard and Sabnzbdplus won't start at boot" is a much more specific title, I think you should rename it.

Comment: Specific and to the point titles all the way!